# How to fix invaild module when using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to compile my python file to executable file using pyinstaller.

I put all the dependent packages and the source python file in one folder.

And I tried pyinstaller --onefile [my python file name].py

It succeeded to build the exe file. However, the exe file fails to run and I checked the warn-[my python script name].txt, there is one invalid module from which I imported the class to my python code.

In my code, I also imported another module, it was working.

```
from autobench.inst import power, func_gen
from autobench.i2c.aa_i2c import AAreadWrite
```

invalid module named autobench.i2c.aa_i2c - imported by C:\Users\jgou\Desktop\test\AP711T_OTP_Program.py (top-level)

Autobench and inst and i2c are folders. Power, func_gen and aa_i2c are python files (.py), AAreadWrite is class in aa_i2c file.

Please suggest what is wrong and how to fix this one. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever manage to fix it? If not, I hope someone else will post an answer.